# Grab data from Wikipedia

Tags: swift, enums, wikipedia

I am building an app which includes inorganic compounds, So I started writing down every compound from this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inorganic_compounds into an `enum` like this:

```
enum IonicCompoundType: Int {
    case AlSb = 1
    case AlAs
    case AlB2
    case AlBr3
    case Al4C3
    case AlI3
    ...
}
```

But I quickly realized it was going to take to long, so my question is, is there a way I can grab the data from that wikipedia site, and automatically put it into an enum (like I was started on writing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot form an enum *dynamically*, in *running* code. You have to form it explicitly beforehand, in Swift, with source text exactly like what you were starting to type.

That said, nothing stops you from copying the text or HTML from the wikipedia page, munging it, and using that to form your Swift code.

Another possibility: don't use an enum! This might not be a very good use of an enum.